# Shared memory with structure and int

Tags: c, pointers, shared-memory

So im having this problem that I want to add "one" structure and one int to my shared memory
And I want to have my "int in the first position of the shared memory" (since i ll need this int in another programs) and then have the structure
This is my code

```
int id = shmget( 0x82488, (sizeof(student)) + sizeof(int) ,IPC_CREAT | 0666 );
exit_on_error (id, "Error");

int *p = shmat(id,0,0);
exit_on_null(p,"Erro no attach");

Student *s = shmat(id,0,0);
exit_on_null (s,"Error");
```

And now comes my question since I have 2 pointers how can I make the int be the first and then the structure, should I just

```
p[0]=100 s[1] = (new Student)
```

Comment: Why don't you write a `struct shared_mem { int count; Student s; }`? Then you only need one pointer to this struct and you can access all the shared memory.

Comment: The memory, which you get from `shmat` is aligned for all possible datatypes. The memory `4` bytes ahead is probably not correct aligned for your struct.

Comment: @WernerHenze I dont use that soluction because I only need that number once

Comment: @Ventura But what do you think is the disadvantage of this struct? What is the cost of having the number available but not using it? How is doing two `shmat` reducing the load?

Answer (score -1):

I would just do

```
int *p = shmat(id,0,0);
exit_on_null(p,"Erro no attach");

Student *s = (Student*)(void*)(p + 1);
```

so that `s` points to where the next int would be if that would be an int.

It is a bit tricky, but clears all possible interoperation issues with possible padding bytes in a struct.

Example:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

In this case, `p` points to the location 0 (relative to the start of the buffer), and thus `p + 1` points to the position 4 (if an `int` has 32 bits). Casting `p + 1` the way I do makes pont `s` to this place, but be of type `Student *`.

And if you want to add a structure `struct extension`, you do the same:

```
struct extension *x = (struct extension*)(void*)(s + 1);
```

This points immediately behind the `Struct` and, again, has the correct pointer type.

Comment: Didnt quite understand but I dont want s to point to int, I want to be able to access the memory and being able to get firstly the int and then the structure

Comment: @Ventura But you want it to point immediately behind your first int, don't you?

Comment: imagine we have an array of multiple objects array*
`array[0] = int
array[1] = strucutre
array[2] = structure`
Something like this
the question is how to implement

Comment: `Student *s = (Student*)(void*)(p + 1);` incorrectly assumes that `p + 1` is properly aligned for a `Student` object.